# Don't work js functions when aspx files any folder

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When I want to move aspx folder to Views Folder master pages javascript functions not working.

How can I resolve this problem.

This code work for when default page aspx file which is in project folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        alert("here");
        $("[id*=txtSearch]").autocomplete({ source: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Handlers/AutoComplete.ashx" ) %>' });
    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found real problem. The real problem is can't resolve js files source, to solve use i have used ResolveUrl

`<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/jQueryUi/jquery.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/jQueryUi/jquery-ui.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>`